# How to choose between integer vs iterable

Tags: python, networkx, iterable

I'm trying to build a subgraph of the Collatz graph, using the following code:

```
def makecollatz(n):
    import networkx as nx
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    G = nx.Graph()
    G.add_node(5)
    for r in range (n):
      for node in [x for x in G.nodes() if G.degree(x)<=1]:
      # for node in [G.nodes() if G.degree(x)<=1]:
          G.add_edges_from(newpair(node))
    nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
    return None; # temp

def newpair (node):
    nodeset=[]
    for x in [node]:
        nodeset.extend({
            1: [[x,int((4*x-1)/3)],[x,int((16*x-1)/3)],[x,int((64*x-1)/3)]],
            2: [[x,int((2*x-1)/3)],[x,int((8*x-1)/3)],[x,int((32*x-1)/3)]]
        }[x % 3])
    return nodeset;

makecollatz(1)
```

The parameter of makecollatz() determines how many iterations the process draws.  It works for n=1 but for larger n it seems to run into problems where I need to send an iterable to the newpair function but I'm sending an integer. I'm not sure how to solve this so it works for all n.  I'm sure it's something simple.

Comment: I solved this problem now. Planning to delete post - is that appropriate?

Comment: I worked out to use         switcher={
            1: [[x,int((4*x-1)/3)],[x,int((16*x-1)/3)],[x,int((64*x-1)/3)]],
            2: [[x,int((2*x-1)/3)],[x,int((8*x-1)/3)],[x,int((32*x-1)/3)]]
        }
        nodeset.extend(switcher.get(x % 3,"No Number"))